Cursor cannot focus in certain areas within a contentEditable element
When inserting an HTML tag with styles into a contentEditable element, in some cases, the cursor cannot focus behind the inserted tag。 The specific steps are as follows：

Insert some characters.
Insert a tag.
Press enter.
Insert more characters.
enter image description here

However, if I skip the first step, the cursor can focus normally behind the tag
enter image description here
Why does this happen? How can I make the cursor position itself behind the tag and continue typing in the first case?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-nova-72hmw4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A65%2C32-65%2C54
Is it possible to position the cursor as expected？

A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not (just) send us to external platforms/playgrounds.
